# Problem with event.target.value in react getting 11 not 1+1

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a series of cards (components) that each carry a number that increments each time a new component is created.
The problem is that instead of adding the value is concatenating and I don't really know how to solve it because I'm a bit new to react.
I have tried to use valueAsNumber or parseInt() but either it doesn't let me or it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import {
  CCol,
  CRow,
  CContainer,
  CButton,
  CCard,
  CCardBody,
} from '@coreui/react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'
import { cilArrowCircleRight } from '@coreui/icons'
import { TableCard } from '../../components'


const Tables1 = () => {

  const [tableID, setTableID] = useState(1);
  const [tablesList, setTablesList] = useState([]);

  const handleChangeID = event => {
    setTableID(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = event => {
    setTablesList([...tablesList, {tableID : tableID}]);
    console.log("Before: " + event.target.value )
    setTableID( event.target.value += 1 );
    console.log("After: " + event.target.value)  
  };
  return (
    <>
    <CContainer fluid>
      <CRow className="mb-4" xs={{ cols: 1 }} sm={{ cols: 2 }} md={{ cols: 2 }} xl={{ cols: 4 }}>
        {tablesList.map((id,index) => {
          return (<CCol key={index} className="mb-4">
          <CCard  className="text-center" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
              <CCardBody>
                  <h2 className="card-title">{id.tableID}</h2>
                  <h5 className="card-title">Table</h5>
                  <div className="d-grid gap-2">
                      {/* <CButton onClick={sendLocation(value+"")}>Send <CIcon icon={cilArrowCircleRight}  /> */}
                      <CButton onClick={() => console.log('Mesa'+id.tableID)}>Send <CIcon icon={cilArrowCircleRight}  />
                      </CButton>
                  </div>
              </CCardBody>
          </CCard>
          </CCol>)
        })}
      </CRow>
    </CContainer>
    <CButton onClick={handleClick}>Add Table</CButton>
    </>
  )
}

export default Tables1
```

And an image:

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3AQN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before addition you first need to convert values into numbers ,so correct way to do this is like

```
const handleClick = event => {
setTablesList([...tablesList, {tableID : tableID}]);
console.log("Before: " + event.target.value )
event.target.value=(+event.target.value)+1
setTableID( (event.target.value );
console.log("After: " + event.target.value)  
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much because I couldn't find the answer. Can I ask you another question? When I press the button two cards come out with the same initial value, it's probably a silly thing that I don't see but I don't know why it happens.

Comment: its because you are initially assign value 1 like this  const [tableID, setTableID] = useState(1);,which is never going to changed so all cards will have same tableID,1.you need to use some random value or you can use last tableId +1 as a next id

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you `event.target.value` is a `string`. If you say `"1" + 1` you will get `11`.

You'll need to convert the value to a number first before trying to do Math on it.

Doing `Number(strNumber)` will convert a `string` value to a `number` if the `string` is a valid `number`.

In you're specific use case here all you'd need to do is change the `handleClick` function to this:

```
const handleClick = event => {
  const value = Number(event.target.value); // converts string value to number
  if (isNaN(value)) return; // stops if value is not a number

  const newId = value + 1; // gets new ID based off the current number value
  setTablesList([...tablesList, { tableID : newId }]);
  setTableID(newId); 
};
```

Comment: It's a pleasure, one of the problems with the ID approach you're taking at the moment is if you've got 2 cards and you add after the second one you'll end up with 3 cards but 2 of them will have the same ID, so you might need to do something different with how you implement all this.

Comment: Yeah, i am trying to do something to modify that but i dont get nothing. Sorry for my english i am spanish.

Comment: It's all good :) One quick option (if you don't plan on deleting tables) is to set the new ID to be the tableList length + 1 (then you don't even need the event value). Usually it's better to just generate unique ids (use the `uuid` npm package) when it comes to id's instead of making it based on the position of the list item.

Comment: I'm thinking about eliminating them later, so I have to give it some more thought.